# Bootstrap two column not inline

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a two column layout with two span6

It's rendering as if there's a `<br clear="all">` after the first span6.

Here's the HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span6">
            left
        </div>
        <div class="span6">
            right
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Typical bootstrap syntax is columns right? `col-md-6`

Comment: Which version of Twitter Bootstrap did you use? Also, why didn't you use `col-*-6` instead of `span6`?

Comment: Wasn't that Bootsrap 2 syntax? I think it was. Check which version you are using

Comment: If you are using version 3, then you syntax is wrong and you should use the one posted above

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  Y'all nailed it.  I'm using version 3.  The answer was to use col-*-6 instead of span6.  Thank you!